# Right-Angled Isosceles Triangle covering puzzle

Tags: geometry, puzzle, triangles

Consider a RAIT (right-angled isosceles triangle), from which we remove a RAIT smaller than half its area by a cut perpendicular to the hypotenuse, like this:

[image]

How many RAITs are required to cover the white part at the right?

The covering RAITs may overlap each other, but they may NOT overlap the black RAIT at the left, and they MUST be contained within the white part.

I managed to find a solution with 3 RAITs:

[image]

This solution works when the black RAIT at the left is sufficiently small. If it is larger, then there is a different solution with 3 RAITs:

[image]

Can you find a solution for these two cases which requires only 2 RAITs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the biggest RAIT has three edges whose lengths are $1,1,\sqrt 2$ and that the black RAIT has three edges whose lengths are $a/\sqrt 2,a/\sqrt 2,a$ with $0\lt a\lt 1$.

Then, I've got the following two :

- If $a\ge 1/2$, then your second solution works because 
  $$\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\ge \sqrt 2\iff a\ge \frac 12.$$
- If $a\le 2/3$, then your first solution works because
  $$(1-a)+\left(1-\frac a2\right)\ge 1\iff a\le\frac 23.$$

These imply that you need at most three RAITs for any size of the black RAIT.

In the following, let us prove that there is no solution with $2$ RAITs.

Since the 'white part at the right' you mention is a quadrilateral, the sum of the inner angles is $360^\circ=180^\circ\times 2$. Hence, if there is a solution with $2$ RAITs, then the two RAITs cannot overlap each other.

By the way, one of the RAITs has to exist at the right-most corner as the following pictures (red ones or blue ones), but in either case, the left part (white part) cannot be in the form of a RAIT (because the black RAIT is smaller than the half of the biggest RAIT). Hence, there is no solution with $2$ RAITs.

[image]
[image]

As a result, we can see that the minimum number of the RAITs one need is $3$ for any size of the black RAIT.

Comment: Interesting. So there is a range (a between 1/2 and 2/3) in which both solutions work.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: Exactly. By the way, I added the proof that there is no solution with $2$ RAITs.

Comment: I think your impossibility proof (or at least the picture) does not cover all possible cases. In particular, it is possible that the red RAIT is rotated. Here, too, the white part will not be a RAIT, so it's still impossible.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: Hmm, I think the red RAIT cannot be rotated. What I meant in my answer is that since the right-most angle of the biggest RAIT is $45^\circ$, this angle has to be covered by a RAIT (by exactly one RAIT because the minimum angle which a RAIT has is $45^\circ$). Therefore, a RAIT has to cover the angle in that form as the pictures. Well, am I mistaken? (I'm not saying my answer is correct!. I'm saying that I'm confused because I cannot find any mistakes in my logic.)

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: Oh, sorry, I got what you mean. Please wait for a minute.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: I added the case you mentioned. Take a look.

Comment: Now I am convinced... thanks!

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: You are welcome! Glad to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The figure in question has adjacent angles of $90-135-90$ degrees.  Two adjacent angles of a right-angled isoceles triangle have $135$ degrees total.  If you put an acute angle of one triangle adjacent to the right angle of another, you're still $45$ degrees short on one angle.  Therefore, there can't be any solutions with $2$ triangles.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The sum of angles in two triangles equals the sum of angles in a quadrangle, doesn't it?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Take a look at your shape.  You have the right angle from the original triangle, a right angle where the chunk was taken out perpendicular to the hypoteneuse, and in between you had what was originally a straight line with a 45 degree segment cut away leaving a $135$ degree angle.  You can break that $135$ degree angle into a $90$ and $45$ degree triangle with no overlap.  The problem is, no matter how you split it, the triangle that has its right angle at the obtuse angle of your shape (pink in your diagrams) has only 45 degree angles next to it.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Assuming the adjacent triangles form a quadrilateral at all, the only $2$ possibilities are a parallelogram or a trapezoid with $2$ adjacent right angles.  Either way, the degree sequence doesn't match up.

Comment: OK, the last comment helped me understand.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, I found proof that a covering with 2 RAITs does not exist. Consider the three segments in the picture below:

[image]

Any covering of the white part must cover all these three segments. Now:

- The red and the green cannot be covered by a single RAIT because the angle between them is 135;
- The green and the blue cannot be covered by a single RAIT because the angle between them is 90 and the only triangle having a 90-degree angle at the top necessarily breaks into the black area.
- The blue and the red cannot be covered by a single RAIT from similar considerations.

Hence we need at least 3 RAITs - one per segment.

Comment: Very nice explanation. +1